# A method to discretize a three-dimensional solid

Tags: regions, computational-geometry, finite-element-method

Consider the following region:

```
eq1 = 4 x;
eq2 = 1/x;
eq3 = 1;
cover = y^2/x^2;
bottom = eq3 < y < eq1 && eq3 < y < eq2;
reg3D = ImplicitRegion[bottom && 0 <= z <= cover, {{x, 1/4, 1}, {y, 1, 2}, {z, 0, 15}}];

RegionPlot3D[bottom && z < cover, {x, 1/4, 1}, {y, 1, 2}, {z, 0, 15}, 
 PlotPoints -> 100, Mesh -> None, AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image]

When I discretize this solid, I get the error messages:

```
DiscretizeRegion[reg3D, AccuracyGoal -> 4]
```

*DiscretizeRegion::drf: DiscretizeRegion was unable to discretize the region ImplicitRegion[<<2>>].*

```
BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[reg3D, AccuracyGoal -> 4]
```

*BoundaryDiscretizeRegion::drf: "BoundaryDiscretizeRegion was unable to discretize the region ImplicitRegion[<<2>>]."*

An attempt with "NDSolve`FEM`ToElementMesh" terminates the C-Compiler.
[image]

Reducing the z domain 0 < z < 9.7; all works fine.

```
new3D = ImplicitRegion[bottom && 0 <= z <= cover, {{x, 1/4, 1}, {y, 1, 2}, {z, 0, 9.7}}];
DiscretizeRegion[new3D, AccuracyGoal -> 4]
BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[new3D, AccuracyGoal -> 4]
```

I am looking for a technique to discretize the whole solid with 0 < z < 15?

Answer (score 2):

Is this sufficient?

```
mesh = DiscretizeGraphics[
 RegionPlot3D[
    bottom && z < cover, {x, 1/4, 1}, {y, 1, 2}, {z, 0, 15}, 
    PlotPoints -> 100, Mesh -> None, 
    AxesLabel -> Automatic] /. _Directive :> {}];

Show[mesh, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Unfortunately not. Sorry, I was not clear enough. My intention is to check volume calculations.Therefor, I need BondaryDiscretizeRegion or DiscretizeRegion. See my last question: "Is DiscretizeRegion not yet ready to discretize 3D-solids?" Thanks for your effort.

Comment: How can I insert hyperlinks in a comment?

Comment: Markdown links are permitted in comments: `[text](url)`.

Comment: @Willinski My understanding is that `DiscretizeRegion` is roughly equivalent to `DiscretizedGraphics@RegionPlot...`, at least for the default settings.  So if there's a problem, it's not `DiscretizeRegion` vs. `DiscretizeGraphics`.  The volume problem, which is distinct from the question you asked here, seems to be the same problem as in your previous question, a degenerate polygon.

Comment: No, DiscretizeGraphics@RegionPlot... is not the same as DiscretizeRegion. You can check it with {RegionEmbeddingDimension@mesh, RegionDimension@mesh} = {3, 2}. You can obtain the Area@mesh but not Volume@mesh.

Comment: @Willinski Thanks, I missed that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative:

```
eq1 = 4 x;
eq2 = 1/x;
eq3 = 1;
cover = y^2/x^2;
bottom = eq3 < y < eq1 && eq3 < y < eq2;
new3D = ImplicitRegion[
   bottom && 0 <= z <= cover, {{x, 1/4, 1}, {y, 1, 2}, {z, 0, 9.7}}];


Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
mesh = ToElementMesh[new3D, "MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.5];
```

To visualize,

```
 Show[mesh[
  "Wireframe"[
   "MeshElementStyle" -> 
    EdgeForm[Directive[Blue, Thickness[0.003]]]]], 
 BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, ImageSize -> {200, 200}]
```

yielding

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: With the reduced z-domain it is ok, however with BondaryDiscretizeRegion or DiscretizeRegion, but not with 0 < z <15.  See my last question: "Is DiscretizeRegion not yet ready to discretize 3D-solids?" Thanks for your effort.