# Find the volume of Phobos and Deimos

Tags: computational-geometry, regions

How can we calculate the volume of a 3D object using the new-in-10 computational geometry functions?

For simple objects this works:

```
shuttle = ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "SpaceShuttle"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Volume@BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[shuttle]
(* 55.5217 *)
```

But [`BoundaryDiscretizeRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BoundaryDiscretizeRegion.html) tends to fail on more complex geometries:

```
{deimos = ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "Deimos"}], 
 phobos = ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "Phobos"}]}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[deimos]

BoundaryMeshRegion::binsect: The boundary curves self-intersect or cross each other in BoundaryMeshRegion[{{-0.473472,5.76096,0.000999842},{-0.32066,5.70981,0.233476},{-0.0747657,5.65315,0.231889},<<46>>,{-2.88191,5.74069,0.489521},<<9360>>},{{},{},{Polygon[{{1,2,3},<<49>>,<<18766>>}]}}]. >>
```

**In general, what is a good way to proceed when we need to treat an object as a solid 3D volume (not surface!) for various purposes, such as triangulation, solving a PDE inside it, calculating a volume, or using it as an integration region?**

Here are two more practical test cases:

```
bunny = ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "StanfordBunny"}]
horse = ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "Horse"}]
```

The Stanford bunny is especially relevant because originally it was created from voxel data (a common application).

Comment: That is an unanswered question, hopefully not. See my questions [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/92292/is-discretizeregion-not-yet-ready-ro-discretize-3d-solids) and [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/94209/a-method-to-discretize-a-three-dimensional-solid)

Comment: I was going to suggest a Montecarlo method, but then I saw you want to use computational geometry procedures...

Comment: @Peltio With the sorts of Monte Carlo volume computations I'm familiar with, you need to be able to tell if any point is inside or outside of the object.  How would you do this here?  If you can do that, that alone seems valuable enough to post.

Comment: My comment (which I deleted before hitting enter and writing this) was "*IF* you can find an efficient test to tell if a point is inside or outside the shape, you could try a Montecarlo method: generate random points in a cube containing your shape e see what fraction of them is inside the volume." (emphasis added now) :-)

Comment: @Peltio Sorry, I did not see that comment!

Comment: Off the top of my head: slice the solid surface into intersection with parallel planes and then use one of those "is point inside a 2D polygon" test to see if it's inside. (@Szabolcs - you could not have seen my comment, so your question is more than justified). An even easier way: 3Dprint the darn satellites and put them into water to measure the displaced volume :-)

Comment: In computer graphics there are various techniques for turning a bad triangle mesh into a volumetric representation; see [Jacobson et al. (2013)](http://igl.ethz.ch/projects/winding-number/) and the references therein. If Mathematica doesn't have a good way to do it, I would export the vertex positions and normals to a point cloud, use [MeshLab](http://meshlab.sourceforge.net/) to [create a clean mesh](http://meshlabstuff.blogspot.com/2009/09/meshing-point-clouds.html), and import it back into Mathematica.

Comment: So, I have an alpha shapes approach, don't know if you're still interested in this.

Comment: @RunnyKine I don't need it right now, but feel free to post, I'm curious!

Answer (score 11):

**Method 1:**

Not perfect solution in method 1:

```
deimos = ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "Deimos"}, "VertexData"];
demon = ConvexHullMesh[deimos];
Volume@BoundaryMeshRegion[demon]
```

> Volume = 1067.07

**Or:**

```
deimos2 = ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "Deimos"}, "VertexData"];
demon2 = DelaunayMesh[deimos2];
RegionMeasure[demon2]
```

> Volume = 1067.07

**Method 2:**

**EDITED!**

Better solution in method 2:

```
deimos = ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "Deimos"}];
Export["Test.stl", deimos];
(* Importing and editing in Blender 3D.Exporting to Test2.stl file *)
B = Import["Test2.stl", "BoundaryMeshRegion"];
Volume[B]
```

> Deimos Volume = 1023.75

```
phobos = ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "Phobos"}];
Export["TestP.stl", phobos];
(* Importing and editing in Blender 3D.Exporting to Test2P.stl file *)
Bp = Import["TestP2.stl", "BoundaryMeshRegion"];
Volume[Bp]
```

> Phobos Volume = 5778.21

[Deimos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deimos_%28moon%29) volume is 999.78 $km^3$, [Phobos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phobos_%28moon%29) volume is 5783.61 $km^3$ in Wikipedia's.

[Test2.stl file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B24PcHRFIKYZU2VhM1V4UmtlTXc/view?usp=sharing) and [Test2P.stl file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B24PcHRFIKYZUXVEQm9NVERPeVk/view?usp=sharing)

You can also export to other files such as: `*.off, *.ply,*.obj` because they have a
"BoundaryMeshRegion" $->$ geometry representation elements.

I'm import Test.stl file to [BLENDER 3D](http://www.blender.org/), and unchecked `"Scene Unit"`.Click `Import STL`.In `"Edit Mode"` Click`->Mesh->Vertices->Smooth Vertex`. Smooth Vertex's algorithm it's not perfect ,you have to manually edit the  vertex's.Click `"Object Mode"`and `File->Export STL->Test2.stl file`.

> **Errors in the mesh grid**
>   [image][image]

An [HorseImp.stl file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B24PcHRFIKYZY2JiQWUwRWVzRnc/view?usp=sharing) example:

```
 horse = ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "Horse"}];
 Export["Horse.stl", horse];
 (* Importing and editing in Blender 3D.Exporting to HorseImp.stl file *)
 hor = Import["HorseImp.stl", "BoundaryMeshRegion"]
 {RegionCentroid[hor], Volume[hor], Area[RegionBoundary[hor]]}
```

Calculate Centroid,Volume,Surface Area:

> {{0.536307, 0.0310618, -0.0876894}, 0.000256564, 0.0343025}

Then You can for example discretizes the region.

```
BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[hor, AccuracyGoal -> 0.1, 
MeshCellStyle -> {{1, All} -> Opacity[0.4, Orange]}]
```

[image]

Comment: The big problem with these two approaches is that both of them measure the volume of the convex hull, not the volume of the object.  For the horse and bunny it would not even be remotely close.

Comment: @Szabolcs. It applies only to the first method.

Comment: Thank you!  Indeed the second method is accurate, but it involves having to fix the mesh manually.  My actual meshes are quite badly behaved and I'm still playing with various software (Blender or others) to try to automate the process.

Comment: @Szabolcs Largely because of your first comment to this post I decided to try answer the question.

Answer (score 10):

A very simple way of calculating the volume of a non-convex polyhedron appears in equation 15 of the article by Lien and Kajiya, ["A Symbolic Method for Calculating the Integral Properties of Arbitrary Nonconvex Polyhedra"](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/MCG.1984.6429334), Computer Graphics & Applications, Oct 1984.  If all faces are triangular, this does the trick:

```
deimos = ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "Deimos"}, "PolygonObjects"];
Total[Abs[deimos /. Polygon -> Det]]/6
(* 1025.7561 *)
```

Here, `deimos` is a list of triangular `Polygon`s.  The argument of each is a three-element list of 3D Cartesian vertex coordinates.  In the second line, *Mathematica*'s `Polygon[]` function is replaced with `Det[]` to evaluate the determinant of the $3\times 3$ matrix formed by the triangle's vertex coordinates.  Finally, the total of the absolute values of all such determinants is divided by six.

For Phobos, the corresponding result is `5790.5116`.

Comment: That should be `Abs[Total[...]]`, I'm afraid (see eq. 25). Otherwise you will get the wrong answer for polyhedra that do not contain the origin.

Answer (score 6):

Here is another solution of the first, specific question about the volumes of Phobos and Deimos. The idea is to use the polygons provided by example data:

```
polygonObjs = 
  ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "Deimos"}, "PolygonObjects"];
polygonObjs // Length

(* Out[74]= 18816 *)

Graphics3D[RandomSample[polygonObjs, 2000], Axes -> True]
```

[image]

Suppose we have shifted those polygons so all their points have positive z-coordinates. Then we can estimate the Deimos volume by summing the volumes of the truncated prisms made by these polygons and their projections on the xy plane while taking into account which polygons are on top and which are under.

First, we have to figure out which polygons are on top an which are under. We can use the "VertexNormals" data for this.

```
polygonData = ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "Deimos"}, "PolygonData"];
polygonData // Length

(* 18816 *)

vNormals = ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "Deimos"}, "VertexNormals"];
vNormals // Length

(* 9410 *)

pNormals = Map[Mean[vNormals[[#]]] &, polygonData];
pNormals // Length

(* 18816 *)

polygons = polygonObjs[[All, 1]];
```

Here is a sample of polygons and their corresponding vectors (note the shift in the z-axis by 10):

```
sInds = RandomSample[Range[Length[polygons]], 600];
Graphics3D[
 Translate[#, {0, 0, 10}] &@{ Polygon /@ polygons[[sInds]], Gray, 
   Opacity[0.3], Thin, Arrowheads[0.005], 
   MapThread[
    Arrow[{Mean[#1], #2}] &, {polygons[[sInds]], pNormals[[sInds]]}]},
  Axes -> True]
```

[image]

Next we define a function (taken from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31241/how-do-i-calculate-the-area-of-a-polygon-given-its-coordinates)) to find the area of a projected (2D) polygon:

```
PolygonArea = 
 Compile[{{v, _Real, 2}}, Block[{x, y}, {x, y} = Transpose[v];
   Abs[x.RotateLeft[y] - RotateLeft[x].y]/2]]
```

Now we are ready to compute the volume by multiplying the projections` areas with hight means and normals direction signs:

```
Dot[Map[PolygonArea[#[[All, 1 ;; 2]]] &, polygons], 
    (Mean[#[[All, 3]]] + 10) & /@ polygons*
    Sign[pNormals[[All, 3]]]]

(* 1026.06 *)
```

( The result seems closer to the one [pointed out in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deimos_%28moon%29) than the solution using ConvexHullMesh.)

The computation of the volumes of the truncated prisms can be refined to be more precise -- note that I just take the means of the z-coordinates of the shifted polygons. (We can use precise formulas or Integrate.)

This idea is very similar to the mathematical formulas for using type-2 surface integrals to compute volumes, but I was too lazy to implement that.

For Phobos this solution gives 5788.04 which is very close to the one given in [Wikipedia's article on Phobos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phobos_(moon)), 5783.61. Using the `ConvexHullMesh` solution we get again a more overestimated volume:

```
phobos = ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "Phobos"}, "VertexData"];
phobos = ConvexHullMesh[phobos];
Volume@BoundaryMeshRegion[phobos]

(* Out[147]= 5987.53 *)
```

Comment: Note the error message cited in the question: "BoundaryMeshRegion::binsect: The boundary curves self-intersect or cross each other." This gives possible explanation why your method gives overrated estimate.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Is this a comment for the other solution? I am not seeing any messages with this solution and I am not using  `BoundaryMeshRegion`.

Comment: I mean that polygons may actually intersect with each other what can lead to overestimate of the volume.

Comment: Nice idea for computing the volume. One could simply apply [the formula that arises from the divergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyhedron#Volume), $V = \frac13\sum\limits_{\text{face $i$}} \mathbf p_i\cdot\mathbf n_iA_i$, where $\mathbf p_i$ is any point on the face. However, this does not solve the general problem of obtaining an actual volumetric `Region` "for various purposes, such as triangulation, solving a PDE inside it, ... or using it as an integration region".

Comment: @Rahul Right, I made those both points in the first version of the post.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov You are right. I am sorry I didn't read your first comment carefully enough.

Answer (score 3):

I will show an approach that makes use of [this α shapes code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/86196/how-do-i-create-a-triangulated-surface-from-points/86277#86277). The caveat here is that one needs to tune a parameter to achieve the "best" shape. But this could be achieved programmatically, if desired, by seeing how some property (e.g. area or volume) of the object changes as the α parameter is changed slightly. A region where that property doesn't change much as long as it's not close to it's Delaunay triangulation value, should give a close approximation of the true value. Let's import some objects:

```
{deimos = ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "Deimos"}], 
 phobos = ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "Phobos"}],
 bunny = ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "StanfordBunny"}]}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

First, we convert these images into regions using `DiscretizeGraphics`

```
reg = DiscretizeGraphics @ deimos
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

We then collect the coordinates of this region and pass them into the `alphaShapes` function to do its job:

```
coord = MeshCoordinates @ reg;
Volume @ alphaShapes[coord, 4.82]
```

> 989.749

This is impressively close to the actual value ($999.78$). Note that if you increase the α parameter slightly to `4.83` you get a huge jump to $1036.32$ and it stops changing for a while . Below I show what the triangulated output from `alphaShapes` looks like. Note how it captures the true shape of deimos.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For phobos, note how close we get to the actual volume ($5783.61$). In the images below I've placed side by side the discretized image (on the left) and the result from `alphaShapes` triangulated (on the right).

```
{alphaShapes[coord2, 8.69] // Volume,
alphaShapes[coord3, 0.01] // Volume}
```

> {5782.64, 0.0000940232}

Here `coord2` and `coord3` were obtained the same way `coord` was obtained above.

[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]