# How to make a Spherical Cow?

Tags: geometry, image3d

Being a theoretical physicist, I always have a great respect for [Spherical Cow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cow). So I thought about making one myself. I am not sure how can I create (something considered to be the simplest!) this marvel.

One possible way could be using the `ExampleData` for `Cow` and map it on a sphere - something like

```
Show[ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "Cow"}], 
     Graphics3D[Sphere[{-.1, 0, 0.05}, .25]]]
```

[image]

I was wondering if there is a way to apply a continuous deformation to the data to get the final sphere (like blowing a balloon).

Another possible way (which is probably the Spherical cow approach of making a Spherical cow) is to map an image of a cow on a sphere.

```
face = Import["http://cliparts.co/cliparts/6Ty/ogn/6TyognE8c.png"]

cow = Graphics[{Disk[10 {RandomReal[], RandomReal[]}, RandomReal[]] & /@ Range[20],
                Inset[face]}, AspectRatio -> 1,ImageSize -> 500];

ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[u] Sin[v], Sin[u] Sin[v], Cos[v]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi},
{v, 0, Pi}, Mesh -> None, PlotPoints -> 100, 
TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#4, 1 - #5} &), Boxed -> False, 
PlotStyle -> Texture[Show[cow, ImageSize -> 1000]], 
Lighting -> "Neutral", Axes -> False, RotationAction -> "Clip"]
```

[image] [image]

Then it is difficult to manage the legs and the tail.

---

**Fixed volume cow**

Based (copying) on [andre's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/125057/8070)  answer here is a modification.

First, we calculate the volume of the cow and the radius of equivalent sphere

```
cow = ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "Cow"}];
Vcow = NIntegrate[1, {x, y, z} ∈ MeshRegion[cow[[1, 2, 1]], cow[[1, 2, 2]]]]
Rcow = (3/(4 Pi) Vcow)^(1/3)
```

> 0.674671
>
> 0.544086

Now insert `Rcow` in the scaling

```
Table[vcow = NIntegrate[1, {x, y, z} ∈ MeshRegion[(# ((Norm[#]/Rcow)^-coeff)) & /@
 cow[[1, 2, 1]], cow[[1, 2, 2]]]];
Show[cow /. GraphicsComplex[array1_, rest___] :> 
 GraphicsComplex[(# ((Norm[#]/Rcow)^-coeff)) & /@ array1, rest], 
 Axes -> True, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}} 0.6,
 Boxed -> True, PlotLabel -> StringForm["(``), V=``", coeff, vcow], ImageSize -> 200], 
{coeff, 0, 1, 0.25}]
```

[image]

Although the final radius is same as `Rcow`, the volume keeps increasing because, on this sphere, several layers are overlapping on each other (reminds me the [length of British coastline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/How_Long_Is_the_Coast_of_Britain%3F_Statistical_Self-Similarity_and_Fractional_Dimension)) which causes overcounting during the numerical integration.

Comment: I really shouldn't have tapped on this before going yo bed... Now I'm going to be seeing these in my dreams...

Comment: You don't have to make it spherical. _Assume_ it is spherical!

Comment: I'm just glad this question isn't on [Seasoned Advice](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/)!

Comment: @Sumit I think you can apply `NIntegrate` to a sequence of gradually transformed cows, apply `SequenceLimit`, and evaluate the results for spherical adherence. Also I have to say, the attention this question and answers have is getting blown up of proportion.

Comment: @AntonAntonov , I must confess I don't know what is a spherical adherence. What I am trying to do is to reduce the overcounting due to overlapping of layers. There should be a way to generate  a new `MeshRegion` removing the duplicate points. One thing for sure - spherical cow is not the simplest cow as it claimed to be.

Comment: @Sumit It seems to me that this discussion might be helpful -- ["Find the volume of Phobos and Deimos"](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/96125/find-the-volume-of-phobos-and-deimos).

Comment: Very funny your idea

Answer (score 82, accepted):

```
cow = ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "Cow"}];
Manipulate[cow /. GraphicsComplex[array1_, rest___] :>  
                  GraphicsComplex[(# (Norm[#]^-coeff)) & /@ array1, rest],
           {{coeff, .25}, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

**Edit**

To answer to Clément's comment, here is same thing with constant plot range :

[image]

Comment: Neat and simple mapping to a sphere - I like it :)

Comment: This is math and physics as their best. :)

Comment: What would this look like if you wanted to conserve volume? I get the impression that the final sphere is a bit bigger than the original cow.

Comment: @user3490 It is clear that these transformations don't conserve the volume. The final sphere is always the unity sphere. It would be hard to conserve the volume because it is hard to estimate the volume of the cow (which is specified as a surface, not a volume). I would be very interested by a way to estimate the volume enclosed in a surface.

Comment: you can do it by integrating over the region.  `Integrate[1, {x, y, z} ∈ ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "Cow"}, "MeshRegion"]]`. I added it in my question as an edit.

Comment: I joined mathematica.SE just to be able to upvote this question and this answer.

Comment: This looks wrong; the example on Wikipedia shows that the cow and the sphere have essentially the same topology, but your transformation doesn't do this: the head and the legs should expand, not contract. Essentially, your transformation just folds the legs and the head onto the body.  Isn't there a way to create an "inflating" effect. in which you get a sphere as the limit of smoothing the surface?

Comment: @Clément In fact, the head and the legs expand. What is happening is that Mathematica is in a automatic plot-range mode :  during the spreading, the range increase with constant image size, so the scale is reduced. If you have Mathematica, just fix the plot range and it will be clear.

Comment: @Clément : I have added 3 images with *a constant plot range*. It show clearly that all the parts of the cow are in expansion. One see also the the volume get largely bigger.

Comment: @Clément It is nevertheless true that there is a folding effect, ie the mapping of the cow towards the final sphere is injective, not bijective.

Comment: @andre: Thanks. Did you mean surjective in your last comment?

Comment: In any case, I think you spotted the issue that I tried to express: namely, that the mapping isn't bijective.

Comment: @Clément Yes, surjective, sorry. A bijective mapping is surely harder to implement.

Answer (score 31):

Get cow as a mesh region:

```
cow = ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "Cow"}, "MeshRegion"];
```

Take coordinates of 0 cells:

```
coords = MeshCoordinates[cow];
```

Get outer sphere that bounds cow:

```
boundary = RegionBoundary @ BoundingRegion[cow, "MinBall"];
```

You could also try other bounds like "FastCapsule". For example,

```
boundary = RegionBoundary @ BoundingRegion[cow, "FastCapsule"];
```

Compute nearest points on the sphere from cow:

```
npts = RegionNearest[boundary, coords];
```

Manipulate results using a linear transformation:

```
cells = MeshCells[cow, 2];
Manipulate[MeshRegion[(1 - t) coords + t npts, cells], {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Very clever solution!

Answer (score 15):

This answer does not produce very pretty outcomes, but it does correspond to the question request:

> I was wondering if there is a way to apply a continuous deformation to
>   the data to get the final sphere (like blowing a balloon).

One thing this solution is good for -- i.e. more useful than the other solutions :) -- is to derive [autostereograms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autostereogram). See the last section.

### Cow points

Generate random cow points:

```
region = DiscretizeGraphics@ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "Cow"}];
cowPoints = RandomPoint[region, 6000];
ListPointPlot3D[cowPoints, BoxRatios -> Automatic]
```

[image]

### Blowing up the cow (points)

Using this function:

```
Clear[BlowUp]
BlowUp[points_, center_, sfunc_] :=
  Map[sfunc[Abs[# - center]] (# - center) + center &, points]
```

and the *continuous function*:

```
Plot[Evaluate@
  With[{a = 0.11}, 
    Piecewise[{{#, # < a}, {a Exp[2 (a - #)], # >= a}}] &][x], 
{x, 0, 0.6}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

we can blow up the cow points to get something close to a sphere:

```
sphCowPoints = 
  BlowUp[cowPoints, Median[cowPoints], 
   With[{a = 0.11, k = 2}, {1, 1.8, 2} 
     Piecewise[{{k Norm[#], Norm[#] < a}, 
                {k a Exp[2 (a - Norm[#])], Norm[#] >= a}}] &]];
ListPointPlot3D[sphCowPoints, BoxRatios -> Automatic]
```

[image]

### Magic eye spherical cows

Since [Yves Klet mentioned](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/125145/34008) the WTC-2012 one-liners competition and one of my entries was an [autostereogram one-liner](https://antonantonov.wordpress.com/2012/10/23/wtc-2012-one-liner-first-entry/) here is code that generates a simple spherical cows autostereogram:

```
rmat = N@RotationMatrix[-\[Pi]/4, {0, 0, 1}];
tVec = {0.1, 0, 0};
sirdPoints = NestList[Map[# + tVec &, #] &, sphCowPoints.rmat, 5];
Graphics3D[{PointSize[0.002], 
  MapThread[{GrayLevel[0.8 - #2], Point[#1]} &, {Flatten[sirdPoints, 
     1], 0.8 Rescale[Flatten[sirdPoints, 1][[All, 2]]]}](*,Lighter[
  Blue],fence*)}, ViewPoint -> Front, Boxed -> False, 
 ImageSize -> 1200]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Anton. Would it be possible to draw an outer surface (something like a 3DMesh)? I tried to replace the coordinates of the original image with `sphCowPoints`, but it looks like the polygon order also has changed in this process.

Comment: I tried to produce a 3D surface too, but did not get good results. At this point if I continue working on this I would use `Nearest` and related functions to find the points close to each other and make polygons.

Comment: I use your `BlowUp` with with `ReplaceAll` and it seems to work. I put it as an edit.

Comment: @Sumit Ah, of course -- it didn't occur to me to use `ReplaceAll`!

Comment: You don't need that `RegionDistribution` function if you have version 10.2 or above, you can use `RandomPoint` instead. So you can just write `cowPoints = RandomPoint[region, 6000]`.

Comment: @RunnyKine Right, I remembered this after you mentioned it.

Comment: Much cleaner +1.

Comment: @RunnyKine Thank you!

Answer (score 12):

Great minds think alike (either that, or silly ideas rule eternal)... Something quite similar was also part of the [2012 oneliner competition](https://www.wolfram.com/training/special-event/mathematica-experts-live-one-liner-competition-2012/). I pull all vertices through the origin to make it a bit more flashy.

This is the golfed version (which arrives at 131 characters, if properly typeset. Also, note bovino-onomatopoeic use of Greek characters):

```
{{g},{p}} := {{ExampleData@{"Geometry3D", "Cow"}}, {g[[1, 2, 1]]}};
Manipulate[
 g /. g[[1, 2, 3]] -> VertexColors -> (Hue@Random[] & /@ p) /. 
  p -> (# (μ - (1 - μ)/Sqrt[#.#]) & /@ p), {μ, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can see the detailed discussion on this one [here](http://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/video.php?c=282&v=703). Don't miss out on the actual winners, they are amazing.

Comment: Now I am feeling great about myself :).  BTW, since you used colour, do you have an idea about how to put spots on the cow? I tried `VertexColors -> (RandomChoice[{Black, White}] & /@ p)...` with your oneliner but the cow looks more like a zebra. I am trying to use `Graphics[Disk[RandomReal[10, 2], RandomReal[]] & /@ Range[20]]` as a texture like the second example in my question - but nothing good so far.

Comment: Textures may work,  however here the transformation-induced distortions are quite bad here, so probably you'll be better off with some of the other solutions. This one was optimized for brevity only .

Answer (score 8):

Here's a simple way of making the blow-up cow:

```
Manipulate[Show[ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "Cow"}], 
  Graphics3D[Sphere[{-.1, 0, 0.05}, r]]], {r, 0, 0.5},
  SynchronousUpdating -> False]
```

[image]

Changing r changes the size of the sphere. If your computer is slow, you may need to add the `ContinuousAction -> False` option.

Comment: umm, it doesn't look like you are exactly blowing the cow. I was looking for a way to radially expand its outer surface.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the discrete laplacian computed on the mesh by transforming along the thusly computed *mean curvature flow*. This operation is often called called smoothing in [Geometry Processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometry_processing).

You need to take precautions to preserve the volume of the mesh, otherwise it shrinks to 0.

This should be rather straightforward to implement in Mathematica.

Here's a pointer:
https://libigl.github.io/libigl/tutorial/tutorial.html#laplacian

[image]

Comment: "This should be rather straightforward to implement in Mathematica." - then you should show a "straightforward" implementation for this to be a proper answer, no? ;)

Comment: A simple variant of the discrete laplacian operator applied at a vertex computes the difference between a vertex' location and the average location of its neighbors. The smoothing operation resulting from this simply sets each vertex' position to the average of its neighbors. `CurvatureFlowFilter` does something similar for images. There, that's some more pointers for looking up the theory, I'm not giving out the full answers here ;)

Comment: To anybody else reading this: since the answerer is not willing or able to post sundry code, you might be able to use some pieces from [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/118283) if you wish to pursue this approach.