# Volume Deformation

Tags: geometry, mesh, splines

I want to do a volume deformation based on Bezier volumes. For example, if I have a triangle mesh, then I want to deform the mesh into a weird shape like the example image attached here. Can anyone give me a simple example on how to implement it?

[image]

Comment: Look up [`BezierFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BezierFunction.html) and [`MeshCoordinates`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshCoordinates.html).

Comment: 2D example: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/34838/4999; 3D example (albeit a fairly plain one): https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/101291/4999

Comment: Thanks. But, those example does not use Bezier curve or volume principle.

Comment: A deformation is simply a transformation (function) applied to the mesh coordinates, the same whether it is an area or a volume. The only difference is the number of coordinates. Can't you use your Bezier function to do that?  What is the "volume principle," if deforming a sphere to an ellipsoid does not use it?

Comment: other example: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/125043/how-to-make-a-spherical-cow